# Why doesnt the old widget get removed?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

Because of the mouseEvent, I would expect the red and blue widgets to switch places on every click. Instead the red switches to the blue and then it never switches back, why?

```
Frame *red = NULL;
Frame *blue = NULL;
bool isRed = true;

Frame::Frame(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent)
{
}


Frame::~Frame(){
    printf("deleted.\n");
    fflush(0);
}
void QLayout_clear(QLayout* layout, bool deleteWidgets){
    QLayoutItem* item;
    QLayout* childLayout;
    while ((item = layout->takeAt(0)) != NULL){
        QWidget* widget = item->widget();
        if (widget != NULL){
            layout->removeWidget(widget);
            if (deleteWidgets){
                delete widget;
            }
        } else if (childLayout = item->layout()){
            QLayout_clear(childLayout, deleteWidgets);
        }

        //delete item;
    }
}

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    this->setLayout(layout);

    red = new Frame;
    red->setFixedSize(100,100);
    red->setStyleSheet("background-color:red");

    blue = new Frame;
    blue->setFixedSize(100,100);
    blue->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");

    layout->addWidget(red);
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *){
    printf("clicked.\n");
    fflush(0);
    QVBoxLayout *layout = (QVBoxLayout *)this->layout();
    if (1){ //it doesnt matter if this is 1 or 0
        delete layout;
        layout = new QVBoxLayout;
        this->setLayout(layout);
    } else {
        QLayout_clear(layout, false);
    }
    if (isRed){
        layout->addWidget(blue);
        isRed = false;
    } else {
        layout->addWidget(red);
        isRed = true;
    }
}
```

Note: here I am using a simple QFrame for the widgets to switch, in my application the widgets are much more complicated and I cannot recreate them every time I want to swap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not good practice from performance point of view to delete and recreate layers each time you want to switch frames, it would be easier to add both frames to the layer and then set visible only frame you want to appear. Also, boolean isRed is not necessary as info about visibility is contained within each frame itself...

Try this:

```
QFrame *red = NULL;
QFrame *blue = NULL;

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent)
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);

    red = new QFrame(this);
    red->setFixedSize(100,100);
    red->setStyleSheet("background-color:red");
    red->setHidden(false);

    blue = new QFrame(this);
    blue->setFixedSize(100,100);
    blue->setStyleSheet("background-color:blue");
    blue->setHidden(true);

    layout->addWidget(red);
    layout->addWidget(blue);
    this->setLayout(layout);
}

void Widget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *){
    printf("clicked.\n");
    fflush(0);
    red->setHidden(!red->isHidden());
    blue->setHidden(!blue->isHidden());
}
```

Comment: +1 because this does indeed work, but I would like to know why the example doesnt.

Answer (score 2):

The layout destructs its children. Because `addWidget` takes ownership so `delete layout` will delete red and blue widgets too.

Comment: @chacham15: Your `QLayout_clear` also deletes the children.  It doesn't just remove them.

Comment: @chacham15 That's the problem and it is still here :)

Comment: really? how do the widgets get deleted? deleteWidgets is false!

Comment: @chacham15 Function `QLayout_clear` does `delete item` everytime. It causes destruction of widget.

Comment: so deleting the `QLayoutItem` causes the widget to be deleted too? How do you delete the `QLayoutItem` without deleteing the widget?

Comment: @chacham15 `layout->removeWidget(blue);` and you can also do `layout->addWidget(red);` to perform your swap. You don't need to delete whole layout.

Comment: @fasked try the new example: "deleted" never gets printed out.

Comment: @chacham15 you have removed Frame from layout but according to Qt doc on `QLayout::removeWidget(): After this call, it is the caller's responsibility to give the widget a reasonable geometry or to put the widget back into a layout.` so you may need to set  (red->hide() or blue->hide()).

Comment: @doc lol, doesnt that defeat the purpose? if it isnt in the layout, why does it need to be hidden? If thats the case, I guess the other answer is the correct one.

Comment: @chacham15 because it is in the layout no more? ;). Layout can manage your widgets until they are within it. The natural approach for Qt is in the Ilya Kobelevskiy's answer.